# How can a GET form be submitted with variables in a specific order?

Tags: forms, url, get

I am building a form that will be submitted to a different website (which I have no control over or ability to change). Oddly enough, the other site seems to require the queries be in a specific order to work correctly. Is there a way to specify how the submitted GET query will be ordered? I've tried ordering the fields in the form, but it doesn't seem to work consistently.

As an example, 1. works fine, while .2 throws an error.

1. http://minerva.maine.edu/search/?searchtype=t&searcharg=caterpillar
2. http://minerva.maine.edu/search/?searcharg=caterpillar&searchtype=t

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware of, however, ugly a solution as it is you could just build your URL in javascript and use `window.location` to send your GET?

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that I'm creating the form on a CMS built on Active Server Pages in which I have no control over anything other then the content area box. Javascript is workable, but not anything post-form-submission